# Vulkan ‘VK_INSTANCE_CREATE_ENUMERATE_PORTABILITY_BIT_KHR’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: linux, compilation, vulkan

I am trying to compile a Vulkan project on my Linux VM (having a windows 10 laptop). I get an error when doing this.

Here is the compiling command and the error I get :
g++ -std=c++17 -Iheaders -O2 -o A01 A01.cpp -lglfw -lvulkan -ldl -lpthread -lX11 -lXrandr
In file included from A01.cpp:3:
modules/Starter.hpp: In member function ‘void BaseProject::createInstance()’:
modules/Starter.hpp:477:23: error: ‘VK_INSTANCE_CREATE_ENUMERATE_PORTABILITY_BIT_KHR’ was not declared in this scope
477 |   createInfo.flags |= VK_INSTANCE_CREATE_ENUMERATE_PORTABILITY_BIT_KHR;
|                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modules/Starter.hpp: In member function ‘std::vector<const char*> BaseProject::getRequiredExtensions()’:
modules/Starter.hpp:511:28: error: ‘VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_ENUMERATION_EXTENSION_NAME’ was not declared in this scope
511 |   if(checkIfItHasExtension(VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_ENUMERATION_EXTENSION_NAME)) {
|                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I have searched throughout the internet and couldn't find any installable libraries that may contain these global variables. As I'm new to the Vulkan environment, I have no idea where this could come from... Would appreciate some help, thanks